# cuda gemm transpose with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, linear-algebra, cublas

I am wondering how the [GEMM](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm) Transpose works. I have a matrix which I want to multiply and I want to multiple the sample matrix transposed. Such as A.T * A

I have something like this,

```
def bptrs(a):
  return gpuarray.arange(a.ptr,a.ptr+a.shape[0]*a.strides[0],a.strides[0],dtype=ctypes.c_void_p)

handle=cublasCreate()
A=np.ones((s,3)).astype(np.float64)
B=A.T # transposed

m,k=A.shape
k,n=B.shape

a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(A)
b_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(B) # I am guessing I need to do a copy since A.T is a view
c_gpu = gpuarray.empty((m,n), np.float64) #Not 100% sure if this is right. I want to get a view returned, so I can save on memory

alpha = np.float64(1.0)
beta = np.float64(0.0)

cublasDgemmBatched(handle, 't','n',
n, m, k, alpha,
b_arr.gpudata, m,
a_arr.gpudata, k,
beta, c_arr.gpudata, m, 1)
```

I am using Cublas 7

Comment: It's fine to put a bounty on the question, but you are going to have to explain in more detail what it is you actually want to know. What does " I have a matrix which I want to multiply and I want to multiple the sample matrix transposed" mean? A few vague semi-questions in your Python code doesn't really help

Comment: Also, you are asking about dgemm in your text, but then showing a call to `cublasDgemmBatched`in the code. They are very different things. Which to do actually want to use here? And finally, how are you actually calling CUBLAS from within Python? Is it via `scikit-cuda`? or something else?

Answer (score 3):

To do A^T A use the cublas `syrk`-function instead of `gemm`.

If you want to understand `gemm` then you have to carefully read the documentation. Don't bother performing the transposition in python as `gemm` have arguments to do it on the fly. Something like this should get you what you want:

```
s = ...
k = 3

handle=cublasCreate()
A = np.ones((s,k)).astype(np.float64)

a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(A)
c_gpu = gpuarray.empty((k,k), np.float64)

alpha = np.float64(1.0)
beta = np.float64(0.0)

cublasDgemm(handle,
            't', 'n',  # A^T A
            m=k,  # number of rows of matrix op(A) and C.
            n=k,  # number of columns of matrix op(B) and C.
            k=s,  # number of columns of op(A) and rows of op(B).
            alpha,
            a_gpu.gpudata, s,  # lda x m with lda>=max(1,k)
            a_gpu.gpudata, k,  # ldb x k with ldb>=max(1,n)
            beta,
            c_arr.gpudata, k,  # ldc x n with ldc>=max(1,m)
            )
```